# running protractor causes npm ERR! weird error 8

Tags: angularjs, node.js, npm, protractor

I was trying to set up nodeJs for AngularJs on my operating System (Ubuntu 14.04) following this: [guideline for installing angular js components](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial) 
but when tried running the last command, found this error. Can any one help.

```
usman@usman-cs:~/angular-phonecat$ npm run protractor
```

> angular-phonecat@0.0.0 preprotractor /home/usman/angular-phonecat
>   npm run update-webdriver
>
> angular-phonecat@0.0.0 preupdate-webdriver /home/usman/angular-phonecat
>   npm install
>
> angular-phonecat@0.0.0 postinstall /home/usman/angular-phonecat
>   bower install
>
> angular-phonecat@0.0.0 update-webdriver /home/usman/angular-phonecat
>   webdriver-manager update

selenium standalone is up to date.
chromedriver is up to date.

> angular-phonecat@0.0.0 protractor /home/usman/angular-phonecat
>   protractor test/protractor-conf.js

```
Starting selenium standalone server...
[launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[launcher] Process exited with error code 1

events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: spawn ENOENT
    at errnoException (child_process.js:988:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:779:34)
npm ERR! weird error 8
npm WARN This failure might be due to the use of legacy binary "node"
npm WARN For further explanations, please read
/usr/share/doc/nodejs/README.Debian

npm ERR! not ok code 0
usman@usman-cs:~/angular-phonecat$
```

Comment: `ENOENT` error is generally caused when something is not found. Error says you may have a legacy node binary and it could be possible that npm is looking for something thats not found. Check whether your installs are in order

Comment: You might have the wrong "node" binary installed on your path.  What does `which node` or `where node` say?  (Or if you run `node` do you get a nodejs prompt or something else?)  *As the error says*, read /usr/share/doc/nodejs/README.Debian

Answer (score 1):

I think you should run `npm install` on the project directory.
That should install all required dependencies. If that don't work, then there are missing dependencies in your `package.json` file.
I you followed the tutorial there shouldn't be any problem.

Comment: thanks! i was indeed in a deeper directory. such a silly mistake